# QFJ Passes Messages in the Wrong Order

Tags: java, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am using QFJ 2.1.1 and testing my application against a fix simulator (also running in QFJ 2.1.1)

There are two fix sessions. 
An initiator and acceptor on both sides.
The problem workflow looks like this:

```
1. simulator/acceptor  <--- New Order Single <--- application/initiator
2. simulator/acceptor  ---> ACK              ---> application/initiator

3. simulator/initiator ---> New Order Single ---> application/acceptor
4. simulator/initiator <---              ACK <--- application/acceptor
```

The order of fix messages processed by QFJ in the simulator is 1,2,3,4
The order of fix messages processed by QFJ in the application is 1,**3,2**,4

The Application was called back with 3 (NewOrderSingle) before it was called back with 2 (ACK)

Here are the QFJ log snippets from the simulator showing 2 and 3 being sent on two sessions:

```
2
2019-12-12 10:23:12.820 [928630][QFJ Message Processor][INFO ] <-- OUTBOUND VENDOR: 8=FIX.4.2|9=180|35=8|34=2|
52=20191212-15:23:12.820|11=287:MACGREGOR-37392703:45037843|17=BYHWG|20=0|37=SIM:287:MACGREGOR-37392703:45037843|38=10000|39=0|54=2|55=MSFT|150=0|10=132|[:]

3
2019-12-12 10:23:12.820 [928630][QFJ Message Processor][INFO ] <-- OUTBOUND ATS: 8=FIX.4.2|9=208|35=D|34=2|52=20191212-15:23:12.820|11=GSET:287:MACGREGOR-37392703:45037843|18=M|21=1|38=10000|40=P|44=153.3
500|54=2|55=MSFT|60=20191212-15:23:09.205|110=0|8011=287:MACGREGOR-37392703:45037843|10=207|[:]
```

Here are the QFJ log snippets from the application showing 3 being received before 2 on the two sessions:

```
3
2019-12-12 10:23:12.824 [31181][QFIXManager][INFO ] FIX onAppReceived(): AQUA->GSET, message=[11=GSET:287:MACG
REGOR-37392703:45037843 35=D 18=M 44=153.3500] {11=GSET:287:MACGREGOR-37392703:45037843, 44=153.3500, 55=MSFT,
 34=2, 56=AQUA, 35=D, 8011=287:MACGREGOR-37392703:45037843, 49=GSET, 38=10000, 18=M, 110=0, 8=FIX.4.2, 9=208, 
60=20191212-15:23:09.205, 40=P, 52=20191212-15:23:12.820, 21=1, 54=2, 10=207} [:]

2
2019-12-12 10:23:12.827 [31184][QFIXManager][INFO ] FIX onAppReceived(): AQUABORG->GSETBORG, message=[11=287:M
ACGREGOR-37392703:45037843 37=SIM:287:MACGREGOR-37392703:45037843 35=8 39=0 150=0] {11=287:MACGREGOR-37392703:
45037843, 55=MSFT, 34=2, 56=AQUABORG, 35=8, 37=SIM:287:MACGREGOR-37392703:45037843, 49=GSETBORG, 38=10000, 17=
BYHWG, 39=0, 150=0, 8=FIX.4.2, 9=180, 52=20191212-15:23:12.820, 20=0, 54=2, 10=132}
```

As you can see, the application messages 2 and 3 are received out of order.

How can I prevent this in my QFJ application?

Comment: They're separate threads, separate TCP sockets and separate sessions. There's probably nothing you can do. Why is this an issue - FIX sessions are bi-directional, you don't need both to communicate with a counter-party.

Comment: Even if you have a TCP pcap showing they were sent over the wire in the right order, you're still at the mercy of socket logic as to which port gets read from first. Then you're at the mercy of the thread scheduling logic as to which acceptor processes it first.

Comment: It turns out that it really doesn't matter. It's not likely to happen in production.  The simulator, in this case, is running on the same machine.